# Grammar of "all are agreed"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

The oft-used phrase "all are agreed" doesn't make grammatical sense to me.

It means "all agree" or "all agreed", or even "all are agreeing", with "all" being the subject.

"All are agreed" instead appears to make "all" the object, with some unspoken subject, as might be the case with "all are accredited" or "all are married". So what would be the subject here?

Or is the phrase just an idiosyncratic idiom? And if so, I wonder how it came about?

(Of course, it could mean "all are engaged in being greedy" I suppose :-) )

Comment: Why do you say all is the object of those other sentences?

Comment: Nothing idiosyncratic about it. _(of two or more parties) holding the same view or opinion on something._
"all the republics are **agreed** on the necessity of a common defence policy." It's just used as an adjective here.

Comment: @Damila Because "Joe and Mary are accredited" means that somebody else has accredited them. "Joe and Mary are married" means that a pastor (for example) performed the marriage. Or you could say that Joe married Mary, and vice versa. In these cases 'are x-ed" means that an x action was done to the x-ee(s).

Comment: @user405662 Are you saying that here"agreed" is not the past tense of agree, but rather some separate adjective that happens to have the same spelling as the past tense?

Comment: It's indeed the past tense of _agree_ used adjectivally. Similar: _They **spent** the entire money on clothing._; _The **spent money** was given X._

Comment: @user405662 Right. So the money is the object in the first sentence. Something was done to it -- the spending of it. And then spent is used as an adjective on the thing that was the object of the spending. Comparing that to "all are agreed", this implies that some agreeing was done on them, where in fact they agreed on some other subject. At best, each person agreed _with_ the others, but that doesn't make the others "agreed" in the same way that if I sing _with_ someone it doesn't make them "sung". At least grammatically speaking.

Comment: @user405662 To put it another way, suppose I said "The committee members met to consider the budget requests. They were all agreed." Does "they" refer to the budget requests (all approved) or to the committee members (they all agreed with each other, possibly to reject the budget requests).

Comment: @gwideman You need to revisit the definition of _object_ and _adjectives._ Adjectives modify nouns as in _spent money_, whereas transitive verbs take objects after them as in _spent the money._ You are confounding things here.

Comment: And in your "budget example", _they_ refers to the members, of course. _requests_ are _agreed upon._

Comment: And please read the example sentence I've quoted above as _The spent money was given by X._

Comment: @user405662 You don't seem to have noticed that I did read your comment about spent, and replied to it.  As for your assessment that "they" refers to the committee members, that just seems bizarre to me. I would say that the committee members "all agreed", for sure. But choosing "the committee members _are_ all agreed" over "the budget requests are all agreed" is very odd. I concur that you _could_ say "all agreed upon", but the "upon" seems now commonly omitted. Either choice seems to depend on ignoring grammar with my choice being the lesser abuse, at least as it seems to me.

Comment: I had missed **by** initially, that's why I rewrote the sentence. I don't know how to proceed further with this question. Sorry I couldn't help. :)

Comment: @user405662 Thanks for the discussion. I see dictionaries may or may not list "agreed" as an adjective modifying the agreed-upon topic (minus "about"), and they may or may not list it as an infinitive/adjective modifying agreeing persons ("we are agreed"). M-W claims the form "I agreed <topic> with him" is chiefly British, which explains my finding that more familiar. Perhaps these various uses of "agreed" (as adjective minus "with", "upon" etc, or "to be agreed") just arose by erosion despite not-quite-grammatical agreement with the past form of "agree".

Answer (score 1):

***To [be agreed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-agreed)*** is an idiomatic expression, often followed by the preposition “on” or the conjunction “that”:

> if people are agreed, they have discussed something and agree about what to do:
>
> be agreed on
>
> - *All parties are now agreed on the plan.*
>
> be agreed that
>
> - *We’re all agreed that we cannot spend what we have not earned.*

(Longman Dictionary)

Comment: Yes, I think I already demonstrated that I know what the phrase means. I'm asking how that makes sense grammatically, and if it doesn't, then how did it get that way.

Comment: @gwideman - agreed is an adjective here. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/agreed

Comment: Yes dictionaries are obliged to report how words are used, regardless of grammar :-).  You happened to find a dictionary that reports "agreed" as an adjective/infinitive both for the agreers ("we are all agreed"), and for the agreed-upon topics ("the agreed price"). Other dictionaries may or may not include one or the other, it appears. But my question is not about whether these are currently used (they are), but rather about how they do or don't derive from "to agree"'s simple past tense "agreed".

Comment: @gwideman - “agreed” in “we are agreed” does derive from verb form to agree. Past participle of some verbs are often used also as adjectives.. given, taken..etc.

Comment: @user66974 [Markdown has changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark). Please join your quotes together with `>` if they are a single quoted passage. Markdown no longer accepts blank lines as part of a quote. (Note you can add two spaces to the end of a line to force a newline as well)

Comment: @gwideman  *But my question is [...]  about how they do or don't derive from "to agree"'s simple past tense "agreed".* No it is not. Please reread your own question. It is very simple: past participles are used as adjectives. "I sold him the car for the agreed/precise/modest, etc., sum."